# Class only works when defining value as argument in constructor

Tags: php, oop

It seems that running a class without defining the value of property as argument, should work. Could someone please clarify why test-1 below does not work?

```
// Test-1: Property defined without value.  This does not work.

class my_class1 {

    private $color_1;

    public function __construct($color_1)
    {
        $this->color_1 = $color_1;
    }
}

// Test-2: Property defined with value. This works.

class my_class2 {

    private $color_2;

    public function __construct($color_2 = 1)
    {
        $this->color_2 = $color_2;
    }
}
```

**Wanted behaviour:**

Test-1 should work without having to define a variable as argument in the class constructor.

Comment: The first one should work as long as you pass a parameter to it when you instantiate it: `$x = new my_class1(2);`

Comment: It works for me ... What errors/issues are you facing ?

Comment: @MER Seems I have missed that I need pass a parameter when instantiating the class. If you clarify this in an answer I will go ahead and approve it.

Comment: The second class defines a default value (`1`) for the construct argument here `($color_2 = 1)` whereas the first one doesn't. It means it is required to pass a value to the first class. By the way, you're not obliged to add a number suffix to class properties to differentiate them, following OOP, it could be named `$color` in both of them without confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a default set on a parameter in the constructor, you will need to specify a value for that parameter when you instantiate the class.

```php
$object1 = new my_class1(); // error

$object1 = new my_class1(2); // valid
// $this->color_1 == 2
```

By adding the default value, it will use the value if you don't specify the value during instantiation:

```php
$object2 = new my_class2();
// $this->color_2 == 1

$object2b = new my_class2(5);
// $this->color_2 == 5
```